# pow wont run on rails new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack-pow

`pow` won't run on `rails new` with a simple static controller and a root of `static#index`

- rails -v = 4.2.1
- ruby -v = 2.2.2p95
- OS X Yosemite (everything updated)

`pow` is working for other apps I have.

The error message is:

```
Your Rack app raised an exception when Pow tried to run it.`

Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find minitest-5.6.1 in any of the sources
```

I even tried throwing in `gem 'minitest', ~>'5.6.1'`

I'm totally lost

Comment: Try running bundle install --path vendor and try running your app again.

Comment: omg, you ROCK!!!! Thank you!!!!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you, but in case someone else runs into this problem, it would be good to come up with an actual answer (installing gems into the vendor directory was a band aid to get you up and running). Any chance you're running rbenv as well?

Comment: mmmm, I think I'm using chruby and ruby install actually